# Why onReceive is not called extending BroadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

the onReceive method isn't called for some reason
I've not applied any filters or anything,

Here is the class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class RegisterListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final int DELAY_TIME = 5;
private int m_seconds = 0;
private int m_minutes = 0;
private int m_hours   = 0;
static ArrayList<BroadcastReceiverListener> listeners = new ArrayList<BroadcastReceiverListener>();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("ScreenReceiver Action:",intent.getAction());

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    m_seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    m_minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    m_hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    for (BroadcastReceiverListener listener:listeners){
           listener.onReceive(m_hours, m_minutes, m_seconds);
        }
}


public static void addBroadcastReceiveListener (BroadcastReceiverListener listener){
    if(!listeners.contains(listener)){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

public void removeBroadcastReceiveListener (BroadcastReceiverListener listener){
    if(listeners.contains(listener)){
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

Here is the declaration in the manifest (child of Application)

```
<receiver android:name=".RegisterListener"></receiver>
```

***Edit :*** 
This is the filter i tried to add (inside the onReceive() )

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new RegisterListener();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

I get an error :

```
The method registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter) is undefined for the type RegisterListener
```

Comment: Looks fine, how do you broadcast your Intents? Post this code.

Comment: How about an `intent-filter` in the receiver declaration; check out http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: I want to catch `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` , before i add any filters, shouldn't i catch any intent without it ? anyway, i tried to add filters but if i add a filter, it can't find the `registerReceiver` method.

Comment: My answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/40826231/6684508 might be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you always want to listen for `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`, try:

```
<receiver android:name=".RegisterListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

**Explanations**

```
The method registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter) is undefined for the type RegisterListener
```

You must use `registerReceiver()` with a Context, for example `context.registerReceiver(...)`. **But:**

> This is the filter i tried to add (inside the onReceive() )

It doesn't make sense to register a receiver *inside* `onReceive()` because `onReceive()` will not run until you have registered a receiver... So it will never happen.  You can put this code in `onCreate()` in your Activity, like this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new RegisterListener();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

This will only listen for `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` *while* your app is already running.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_STARTED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_SUCCESS_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_FAILURE_ACTION);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, intentFilter);
```