# IntentService LocalBroadcastManager not reaching Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, localbroadcastmanager

I'm using Android Studio 1.3, I have an `IntentService` setup that gathers some data and sends it out via a `LocalBroadcastManager` as so:

**IntentService**

```
public class cService extends IntentService {

    public cService(){
        super("cService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("action.getTestData");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("data", response.toString());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

The above code runs, but the Broadcast is never captured.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".services.cService"
         android:exported="false">
</service>

<receiver android:name=".services.Receiver">
</receiver>
```

**Receiver which extends BroadcastReceiver** (Never gets called)

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    protected MainActivity mainActivityContext;

    public Receiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");

        mainActivityContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView txtData = (TextView)mainActivityContext.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txtData.setText(data);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**MainActivity onCreate()**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView txtData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Dummy text field that should populate with something upon
        //onReceive() executing...
        txtData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txtData.setText("Ready.");

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("action.getTestData");
        filter.addDataScheme("string"); 

        BroadcastReceiver c = new Receiver();
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(c,filter);

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here that's causing the Broadcast to not be received? I'm thinking it has to do with my `IntentFilter`?

Comment: @Anthea I posted my answer on how I managed to get mine to work. Its been working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem I had by incorporating `BroadcastReceiver` within `onResume()` of my `MainActivity`. My goal here was to simply capture that data once the `Service` completed retrieving all network data.

I hope this helps someone...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private boolean isReceiverRegistered;
        private Button btnRetrieveRouteData;
        private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //UI Component Instances
            btnRetrieveRouteData =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGetRouteInformation);
            btnRetrieveRouteData.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            if (!isReceiverRegistered) {
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("ma.MainActivity.WebServiceReceiver.ReturnedReceivedDataFilePath");
                receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

                        //Get message from WebServiceReceiver Intent
                        String ReceivedDataFromIntent = intent.getStringExtra("WebServiceReceiver_ReturnedReceivedDataFilePath");

                        //Do whatever with the data received from the Service...
                    }
                };

                //Register the receiver
                isReceiverRegistered = true;
                this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            if (isReceiverRegistered) {
                try {
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                   //Handle Exception as needed...
                }
                isReceiverRegistered = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        public void onClick(View view){
           switch(view.getId()){
               case R.id.btnGetRouteInformation:
                     CallWebService("testParam1", "testParam2");
                   break;

                default:
                    //Do nothing
                   break;
           }
        }

        private void CallWebService(String param1, String param2){

            //Begin web call to retrieve necessary data.
            ServerCaller.GetRequestForRouteWithDriverId(this, param1, param2);

            //WebServiceReceiver will get this returned data and broadcast it; received in "onResume()" here.
        }

    }
```

I then have another classe called `WebServiceReceiver`, this class will handle the result from the webservice, it will prepare the data and then create the intent that our `onResume()` Override method will filter and read in.

```
public class WebServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public WebServiceReceiver() {}


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals("Helper_GetRequestForData")){
            //Retrieve the data from incoming Intent that web service submitted
            final String ReceivedDataFilePathThatContainsData = intent.getStringExtra("Helper_GetRequestForData");

            Intent responder = new Intent("ma.MainActivity.WebServiceReceiver.ReturnedReceivedDataFilePath");
            responder.putExtra("WebServiceReceiver_ReturnedReceivedDataFilePath", ReceivedDataFilePathThatContainsData);
            context.sendBroadcast(responder);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things started working for me once I replaced

```
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

with

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

above.  Of course, this only applies if you're using a local service, internal to  your app.

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting `android:exported=true` in the `<service>` block of your XML. According to the docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported

> The default value depends on whether the service contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that it can be invoked only by specifying its exact class name. This implies that the service is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the service is intended for external use, so the default value is "true".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did this but no luck, still not hitting `onReceive()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(cService.class);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Comment: Just having `cService.class` wont compile. Had to test with `String.valueOf(cbiService.class));` It still didn't make a difference though.