# BroadcastReceiver onReceive() is not working on Fragment using Kotlin MVVM structure

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I'm working on a app that capable of checking all bluetooth device and need to display it on recyclerview on load of the app. Im using `BroadcastReceiver` for the searching of the devices. but apparently, the `onReceive()` method is not triggering.

I've already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706537/why-onreceive-is-not-called-extending-broadcastreceiver-in-android) but still it doesnt work for me.

Please see my code below

BroadcastReceiver

```
class BluetoothBroadcastReceiver(private val listener: Listener) : BroadcastReceiver() {

    constructor() : this(object : Listener {
        override fun onBluetoothDeviceFound(device: BluetoothDevice) {}
        override fun onGpsAction() {}
    })

    interface Listener {
        fun onBluetoothDeviceFound(device: BluetoothDevice)
        fun onGpsAction()
    }

    private val GPS_ACTION = "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND == action) {
            val btd = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            if (btd?.bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                listener.onBluetoothDeviceFound(btd!!)
            }
        } else if (action == GPS_ACTION) {
            listener.onGpsAction()
        }
    }
  }
```

Registering the receiver on `onResume()`

```
 bluetoothBroadcastReceiver = BluetoothBroadcastReceiver(this)
    val intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        addAction(GPS_ACTION)
    }
    try{
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).registerReceiver(bluetoothBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter)
        Log.e("intent","register")
    }catch(e: Throwable){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Listener that is implemented on my fragment

```
override fun onBluetoothDeviceFound(device: BluetoothDevice) {
    if (!deviceIsExist(device.address)) {
        val name = device.name
        datas.add(BluetoothDeviceDetails(name, device.address, false))
        binding.rvPrinterSettingsList.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(datas.size - 1)
    }
}

override fun onGpsAction() {
    if (isGpsOpen()) {
        setBluetooth()
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".broadcastreceiver.BluetoothBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND" />
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are registering for broadcasts that are system level broadcasts (broadcasts not local to your application), you need to register the `BroadcastReceiver` globally, not through the `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Use [Context.registerReceiver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) instead.

Comment: I've tried `requireContext().registerReceiver(bluetoothBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter)` but it still not working

Comment: What are your declared manifest permissions, and have they been allowed?

Comment: `BLUETOOTH` `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` `BLUETOOTH_SCAN`. yes its all allowed